# Opencart, I want to see the category name in my product search

Tags: opencart, categories, product

Small example, I have 3 categories: small tea mug, normal tea mug, and large tea mug. 
The all have the same products: white mug, blue mug, and green mug. The pictures are squares in the same color. So when I search for blue I get 3 hits for blue, but can't see if it is for the small, normal or large. How can I add the category for these products?

Thanks!

Comment: You should have a category *Tea mug*, then three products only (blue, white, green) and three options for each (small, normal, large) with the price changing accordingly (or vice versa - have a small, normal and large mugs as products with different price and have three colors as options). Then you do not need such modifications and your products are not duplicated.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not an option in the real case. I do need the categories.